# For looping over tests in python using pytest

Tags: python, list, api, pytest

I want to perform API testing using pytest. I have API parameters setup as JSON and looping over multiple expectations for each test.

I want assert to fail test and start with another test from JSON data. But I don't see an option of looping over tests except parametrized fixture.

```
def test_cases(self):
        params = {}
        for testcase in testcases:
            for parameters in testcase[2]:
                params[parameters['name']] = parameters['value']
            params['q']=testcase[1]

            API_SERVER_URL ='URL/'
            response = requests.get(API_SERVER_URL, params=params, headers='')
            for expectation in expectations:
                jsonpath_expr = '$.[0].'+ expectation['group_key']+ '.' + expectation['key']
                expected_value = expectation['value']
                actual_value = parse(jsonpath_expr).find(response.json())
                # test_case(actual_value[0].value, expected_value)
                assert actual_value[0].value == expected_value
```

After assert I want to start over with for loop with testcases. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely look into parameterising your tests, but another way is to just collect the failures yourself:

```py
def test_cases(self):
    failures = []
    params = {}
    for testcase in testcases:
        for parameters in testcase[2]:
            params[parameters['name']] = parameters['value']
        params['q']=testcase[1]

        API_SERVER_URL ='URL/'
        response = requests.get(API_SERVER_URL, params=params, headers='')
        for expectation in expectations:
            jsonpath_expr = '$.[0].'+ expectation['group_key']+ '.' + expectation['key']
            expected_value = expectation['value']
            actual_value = parse(jsonpath_expr).find(response.json())
            if actual_value[0].value != expected_value:
                failures.append( (actual_value[0].value, expected_value) )
    assert failures == []
```

So, if there are no failures, then `failures` will still be the empty `list`. otherwise you will see the contents printed out.